# Most efficient way of using an action listener in Java?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I was tasked with creating a program that displays a numeric keypad (like one on a phone) and has a screen that displays the numbers that are picked. Also included is a clear button that clears the screen.

In creating my program, I created three classes. The Phone class simply creates a JFrame that adds a PhonePanel to the screen. The PhonePanel class adds a JLabel which acts as a screen, a JButton which acts as a clear button, and a KeypadPanel which is a GridLayout of JButtons which acts as the numeric keys.

The clear button and numeric buttons both use separate action listeners. Is this the most efficient way of going about this? Is there a way I can use one action listener instead of two?

```
// ******************************************************************************************
// Phone.java
// David Read
// This class creates a JFrame that contains a PhonePanel. The PhonePanel provides a
// user interface that allows one to input numeric symbols on a screen and allows clearing
// of the screen.
// ******************************************************************************************

package lab5;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Phone {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Create a JFrame object.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Phone");

        // Set the default close operation for the JFrame.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Add a Phone panel to the screen.
        frame.getContentPane().add(new PhonePanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}



// ******************************************************************************************
// PhonePanel.java
// David Read
// This class creates a JPanel that includes an output label which displays inputed numeric
// symbols, a clear button that clears what is displayed on the output label, and a KeypadPanel
// which displays a GridLayout of buttons that when pressed, display their corresponding symbols
// on the output label.
// ******************************************************************************************

package lab5;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PhonePanel extends JPanel 
{
    private static JLabel labelOutput;
    private JButton buttonClear;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Creates a JPanel that arranges three objects in a Border layout. The
    // north component contains a JLabel, the east component contains a JButton
    // and the center component contains a KeypadPanel.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public PhonePanel()
    {
        // Set the layout manager, size and background color of the Phone Panel.
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(400, 200));
        setBackground (Color.yellow);

        // Output label created.
        labelOutput = new JLabel(" ");

        // Clear button created, assigned a button title and assigned an action listener.
        buttonClear = new JButton();
        buttonClear.setText("Clear");
        buttonClear.addActionListener(new ClearButtonListener());

        // Add the JLabel, JButton and KeypadPanel to the PhonePanel.
        add(labelOutput, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(buttonClear, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(new KeypadPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);        
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Adds the specified symbol to the output label.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void addToOutputLabel(String input)
    {
        // Create a String object to hold the current value of the output label.
        String label = labelOutput.getText();

        // Append the inputed String onto the String.
        label += input;

        // Update the output label with the appended String.
        labelOutput.setText(label);
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Listens for the clear button to be pressed. When pressed, the output
    // label is reassigned as blank.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    private class ClearButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            labelOutput.setText(" ");
        }
    }
}



// ******************************************************************************************
// KeypadPanel.java
// David Read
// This class creates a JPanel that contains several buttons which when pressed, adds their
// corresponding numeric symbol to the output label in the PhonePanel.
// ******************************************************************************************

package lab5;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class KeypadPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JButton button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, buttonStar, button0, buttonNumber;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Creates a JPanel that arranges several JButtons in a GridLayout. Each
    // of the buttons are assigned button titles, action listeners and
    // action commands.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public KeypadPanel()
    {
        // Set layout to a GridLayout with 4 rows and 3 columns.
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));

        // Create new JButtons.
        button1 = new JButton();
        button2 = new JButton();
        button3 = new JButton();
        button4 = new JButton();
        button5 = new JButton();
        button6 = new JButton();
        button7 = new JButton();
        button8 = new JButton();
        button9 = new JButton();
        buttonStar = new JButton();
        button0 = new JButton();
        buttonNumber = new JButton();

        // Assign button titles to the JButtons.
        button1.setText("1");       
        button2.setText("2");       
        button3.setText("3");       
        button4.setText("4");       
        button5.setText("5");       
        button6.setText("6");       
        button7.setText("7");       
        button8.setText("8");       
        button9.setText("9");       
        buttonStar.setText("*");        
        button0.setText("0");       
        buttonNumber.setText("#");

        // Create a new KeypadButtonListener.
        KeypadButtonListener listener = new KeypadButtonListener();

        // Assign the listener as an action listener for all of the JButton objects.
        button1.addActionListener(listener);
        button2.addActionListener(listener);
        button3.addActionListener(listener);
        button4.addActionListener(listener);
        button5.addActionListener(listener);
        button6.addActionListener(listener);
        button7.addActionListener(listener);
        button8.addActionListener(listener);
        button9.addActionListener(listener);
        buttonStar.addActionListener(listener);
        button0.addActionListener(listener);
        buttonNumber.addActionListener(listener);

        // Set the action commands for all of the JButtons.
        button1.setActionCommand("1");
        button2.setActionCommand("2");
        button3.setActionCommand("3");
        button4.setActionCommand("4");
        button5.setActionCommand("5");
        button6.setActionCommand("6");
        button7.setActionCommand("7");
        button8.setActionCommand("8");
        button9.setActionCommand("9");
        buttonStar.setActionCommand("*");
        button0.setActionCommand("0");
        buttonNumber.setActionCommand("#");

        // Add the JButtons to the KeypadPanel.
        add(button1);
        add(button2);
        add(button3);
        add(button4);
        add(button5);
        add(button6);
        add(button7);
        add(button8);
        add(button9);
        add(buttonStar);
        add(button0);
        add(buttonNumber);
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Listens for all of the buttons to be pressed. When a particular button
    // is pressed, the addToOutputLabel method of the PhonePanel is called
    // with the input being the action command of the button pressed.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    private class KeypadButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            // Add the action command string to the output label.
            PhonePanel.addToOutputLabel(e.getActionCommand());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, can you reduce it to a minimal example ([mcve])? Will be far easier to understand your question then. Or you may try to guide us through the code, where exactly should we look at? Show us some small snippets of the relevant parts.

Comment: If you insist on *single* `ActionListener`, try with `e.getSource()` method which returns an Object who triggered an `ActionEvent`. But, in this case, I recommend at least two listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is better to use two separate action listeners as functionality for clear button and for number buttons is different. 
It is considered as best practice to use single responsibility principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) when developing your classes. This will make your code more maintainable and easier to read and modify.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use multiple ActionListeners here, however, if you still desire to use one ActionListener instead you may make a separate class to handle all actions similar to this.

```
public class KeyListener implements ActionListener {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    //Get the name of the ActionEvent
    String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

    //Here the Actionevent is only checked to see if it is a "Clear" or not
    //If you need to impliment more then a switch statment may be appropriate 
    if(cmd.equals("Clear")) {
        //Clear Label with additional setter method
        PhonePanel.clearLabel();
    }
    else {
        PhonePanel.addToOutputLabel(e.getActionCommand());
    }

}
```